# How to add new class to the existing class in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript and Jquery so please excuse if this is a dumb question

HTML is being constructed dynamically as shown

```
var favoriteresultag = '<ul>';

favoriteresultag += "<section id='"+name+"'  class='ulseWrap lielement'>" + "<div class='intit someclassss'>"+ name + "</div>" + "</section>";
```

How can i add/concat one more  variable  to the class ulseWrap lielement ??

I tried this way

```
var classactive = '';

if (some condition) {
    classactive = 'activeRest';
} else {
    classactive = '';
}

favoriteresultag += "<section id='" + name + "' class='ulseWrap lielement '+classactive+' '>" + "<div class='intit someclassss'>" + name + "</div>" + "</section>";
```

Comment: I'm supposed to be able to read that image?

Comment: You missed double quotes `class='ulseWrap lielement "+classactive+"'`

Comment: With my magnification at 300%, that image has 2 sections one with ID `Home` and one with ID `Office`

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation, just like you're doing:

```
favoriteresultag += "<section id='"+name+"'  class='ulseWrap lielement " + classactive + "'>" + "<div class='intit someclassss'>"+ name + "</div>" + "</section>";
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this with jquery if you are using it

```
$('.actual_class').addClass('new_class')
```

In your case can be

```
$('#'+name).addClass('activeRest')
```

or

```
$('.ulseWrap.lielement').addClass('activeRest')
```